# Set default firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

is it possible to set default function for firebase?

You can access deployed functions using `https://us-central1-[projectname].cloudfunctions.net/function1`,
`/function2` and so on...

but is it possible to set one function to be accessed with `https://us-central1-[projectname].cloudfunctions.net`, as default without using further route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set a default function for the `*.cloudfunctions.net` domain.

HTTP Triggered Cloud Functions in both [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function) and the underlying [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) service both use the URL format:

```
https://YOUR_REGION-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME
```

If you wish to invoke a function by default, you should [serve it from behind Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), where you include the following information inside your `firebase.json` file:

```json
{
 "hosting": {
   // ...

   "rewrites": [ {
     "source": "**",    // rewrite all (non-existant) paths
     "function": "app"  // to the HTTPS Cloud Function called "app"
   } ]
 }
}
```

With that configuration, the URLs `https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.web.app` and `https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com` will both invoke your HTTPS Trigger Cloud Function called "app" (when the path doesn't match a deployed file from your hosting folder).

If you deployed a file called `favicon.ico` from `YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/public` folder, a call to `https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.web.app/favicon.ico` will download that file without invoking the HTTP function.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to making rewrites, you also need to delete the hosting `public/index.html` file to use the default route `/`